# How to evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{e^{i\theta}}{d\theta}$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-integration

I have tried using a parametrization with $z = e^{i\theta}$ to no avail. I would greatly appreciate any solutions or suggestions please. Thanks

Comment: Ah ok I missed the chain rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With $z=e^{i\theta}, dz=izd\theta$, so

$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{e^{i\theta}}{d\theta}=\frac{1}{i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{e^z}{z}{dz}=2\pi$ by the residue theorem

Comment: Thank you, I did not think about using the residue theorem. That clarifies a lot!

Comment: Happy to be of help